# I have a single row Dataframe with a date column. How do I add 10 rows, with each one changing the date by 14 days each time?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

for instance my dataframe is only one row and has two columns, Date and Amount. Date is 1/1/2020 and Amount is $100. I want to add 14 days to the date and add 5% to the Amount, therefore creating a new row. Then do it again, nine more times. What's the best way to do this? I've been Googling and checking various ways to append, add, using loc, iloc, append, where, for loops, and I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Matt, are you able to produce a reproducible example of your input and output dataframe? once you have this it's much easier for others to provide an answer tailored to your needs. Also please show your own attemp. [mcve]

Comment: Sorry and thank you for helping me to provide the necessary info. Here is a quick way to create my dataframe: 

`import pandas as pd
data = [['1/1/2020', 100]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date', 'Amount'])
df`

Comment: my attempts have been several over the past couple of hours and i keep deleting them and overwriting... I've tried so many different things I'm lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Amount'])
day = date(2020, 1, 1)
amount = 100
for i in range(11):
     df.loc[i] = [day, amount]
     day += timedelta(days=14)
     amount *= 1.05
print(df)
```

Result:

```
          Date   Amount
0   2020-01-01      100
1   2020-01-15      105
2   2020-01-29   110.25
3   2020-02-12  115.763
4   2020-02-26  121.551
5   2020-03-11  127.628
6   2020-03-25   134.01
7   2020-04-08   140.71
8   2020-04-22  147.746
9   2020-05-06  155.133
10  2020-05-20  162.889
```

Comment: Thank you, JohanC. I now understand the loc[i] represents the entire row and I need to fill in a value for everything in that row. I think I was trying to use it like loc[row, column] and couldn't get it quite right.